# Laravel Auth::attempt is failling

Tags: php, laravel

My database is correct, I have the proper setup for my authentication, routes and controller and the data in the table is good too what am I doing wrong!!

Routes:
[image]

Login Controller:
[image]

Database:
[image]

It still fails in Postman:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?  When I do the following

```
dd(Users::findOrFail(1));
```

I get the Users with the proper data, Im completely lost now.

Comment: Why is password stored in plain text in the database? That's very wrong.

Comment: I understand, but I did that just for testing purposes for now as I just set this up for my React app, I will use a Hash later

Comment: that is why attempt is failing, you need the password hashed in the database, as the user provider will do a hash check

Comment: Okay thank you will do that now.

Comment: Use postman to make a post request and see what it output. More so I am quite confused if you are making a stateless or stateful login.

Comment: Thank you @lagbox, that worked.  My answer i sbelow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use Auth::attempt() in Laravel, it hashes the password, and then it checks for the provided username and password (hashed password) in the database. If you have stored the password as plain text in database, while creating the user, you can never able to login using Auth::attempt().

So, always make sure that, you hash the password while creating the user. There are many ways to do it

Using Hash:

```
User::create(['email'=>'Your Email ID', 'password'=> Hash::make('Your Password')])
```

Using Password_Hash:

```
User::create(['email'=>'Your Email ID', 'password'=> PASSWORD_HASH('Your Password',PASSWORD_BYCRYPT)])
```

Now, if you do the Auth::attempt() (here, use the plain password), it would work.

Hope it helps. Thank You :)

Comment: Thank you although someone in the comments solved this for me I will set this as the correct answer because the rule is the password is always hashed when using Auth::attempt

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:

The answer to this was thanks to lagbox's response, the Laravel Auth requires the password to be hashed.  Hash it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your create action should hash the password before save it.

```
Hash::make($data['password'])
```

Try something similar:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

public function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```